# When I tried upgrading my project to a newer version of unity, then downgrading it to the original one, it gave me 3 errors having to do with sprites

Tags: unity

So I upgraded my project to a newer version of unity because some dude told me that i could export my game (i couldn't). So I downgraded my project to my original editor version and it gave me these 3 errors:

Library/PackageCache/com.unity.2d.common@6.0.1/Editor/InternalBridge/TexturePlatformSettings/TexturePlatformSettings.cs(158,47): error CS1501: No overload for method 'ShowPlatformSpecificSettings' takes 2 arguments

Library/PackageCache/com.unity.2d.spriteshape@7.0.3/Runtime/SpriteShapeController.cs(338,56): error CS1061: 'SpriteShapeRenderer' does not contain a definition for 'localBounds' and no accessible extension method 'localBounds' accepting a first argument of type 'SpriteShapeRenderer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Library/PackageCache/com.unity.2d.spriteshape@7.0.3/Runtime/SpriteShapeController.cs(339,37): error CS1061: 'SpriteShapeRenderer' does not contain a definition for 'SetLocalAABB' and no accessible extension method 'SetLocalAABB' accepting a first argument of type 'SpriteShapeRenderer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm 100% sure this has nothing to do with my code. Any fixes for these erros?

Comment: Unfortunately the best advice here is "always make a backup of your project before upgrading" (or better, "always have a version control system so you can roll back any breaking changes"). Follow those and you'll be able to solve any upgrade-downgrade issue trivially. But given that you don't have a backup/previous version to roll back to, I'd recommend using the package manager to systematically uninstall/reinstall all the packages you're using with the latest version supported for your editor. Start with the sprite shape since it seems to be causing errors, and report back what you find.